# github push -> redmine issue duplicate comments

Tags: git, ruby, redmine, github

I've successfully connected github to redmine and whenever someone puts an issue reference in a commit message and pushes it to github, a comment is added to the redmine issue referring back to the git commit.  This is all fine and well, except that I end up with duplicates.  I'm not sure what causes the duplicate, but I think it's when the commit is part of a non-fast-forward merge.

What can I do to prevent the duplicates?  I had a look at the github hook to understand how it was getting a list of git commits, but couldn't follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple branches in your repo?

Each time a commit is merged into a another branch, github will trigger the hook and write another comment to Redmine.

Comment: how can i modify the hook so that it excludes already pushed commits?  i know how to do this with a shell command, but i'm very lost when reading the ruby.